# Macht es einen Unterschied ob das Verb das erste oder zweite Wort nach "doch" ist?

Tags: sentence-structure

Wenn ein Satz mit „doch“ anfängt, gibt's irgendeinen stilistischen Unterschied, je nachdem, ob das Verb das erste Wort oder das zweite nach „doch“ ist?  Ein paar Beispielsätze sind unten aufgeführt.

1. Satz:  Doch es war eigentlich gar nicht so schlimm.
2. Satz:  Doch war es eigentlich gar nicht so schlimm.

Ist der zweite Satz überhaupt grammatisch korrekt?

Answer (score 6):

> **Doch diese Frage** beschäftigt mich.
>
> **Doch beschäftigt** diese Frage mich.

Der Unterschied in diesen beiden Sätzen liegt darin, worauf sich *doch* bezieht, auf *diese Frage* oder auf *beschäftigt*.

Bei deinen Beispielen ist es ebenfalls so. Nur kommt das bei der Kopula *sein* und dem sehr schwachen Pronomen *es* nicht gut zur Geltung.

Comment: Im Schriftlichen gibt es keine Betonung durch die Aussprache. Also muss man zu anderen Hilfsmitteln greifen. Und das ist eben die Wortstellung. Im Mündlichen wird man ohnehin durch die Aussprache betonen, und über die Wortstellung kann man in der Eile kaum nachdenken und schon gar nichts korrigieren. Sie ist daher im Mündlichen weniger wichtig.

Answer (score 1):

Laut dem Zweifelsfall-Duden<sup>1</sup> hat die Stellung damit zu tun, ob *doch* als Adverb oder als Konjunktion gebraucht wird. Beim Beispielsatz

> Es war eigentlich gar nicht so schlimm.

ist beides möglich.

#### *Doch* als Adverb

Ich zitiere: "Wenn *doch* oder *jedoch* als Adverbien allein vor dem finiten Verb an der Spitze eines nebengeordneten Satzes stehen, führt das zu einer Stellung des **Subjektes nach dem finiten Verb** [...]".

Bei adverbialem Gebrauch von *doch* muss es demnach heißen:

> Doch war es eigentlich gar nicht so schlimm.

#### *Doch* als Konjunktion

Ich zitiere: "Stehen *doch* oder *jedoch* nicht allein vor dem finiten Verb, dann fungieren sie als Konjunktionen." Und weiter: "[W]enn sie Hauptsätze miteinander verbinden [...], **tritt *doch* immer an den Anfang des Satzes**."

Gehen wir einmal davon aus, dass vor dem Beispielsatz noch ein anderer Satz steht. Dann fungiert *doch* im folgenden Satz als Konjunktion:

> Doch es war eigentlich gar nicht so schlimm.

---

<sup>1</sup> Eintrag *doch / jedoch* im *Duden 9: Das Wörterbuch der sprachlichen Zweifelsfälle. 8. Auflage*

Answer (score 0):

Korrekt sind beide Sätze, ein Unterschied ist allerdings, dass man bei Satz 2 das leise Gefühl hat, dass vor dem Punkt noch etwas kommen müsste.

> Doch war es eigentlich gar nicht so schlimm, dass seine Partei die Wahl verloren hatte.

Soll der Satz kurz bleiben, würde ich daher zu Version 1 raten.

Davon abgesehen spricht nichts dagegen, auch Satz 1 auf die genannte Art zu erweitern.

Answer (score 0):

Der zweite Satz stößt mir mehr auf als der zweite. So ganz ohne Konntext würde ich erstmal beide als ungültige Hauptsätze einstufen.

*Doch* tritt hier als Clitic auf. In Indo Europäischen Sprachen pflegen diese an zweiter Stelle zu kommen und das Verb zu binden. Das Substantiv wird in SVO-Sprachen an erster Stelle Gesetzt. *sein* zält dabei als preverbales Clitic

> Es war doch eigentlich gar nicht so schlimm.

Dabei fällt auf, dass *doch-eigentlich* doch eigentlich redundant ist. Zudem steht auch keine gegenteilige Behauptung im Raum, die widerlegt werden müsste.

> Es war nicht schlimm

Viel besser. Alles andere wäre gebrochenes Deutsch, bzw eine Frage oder Teilsatz

> * war es nicht schlimm

Allenfalls könnte *doch* als diskursmarkierende Interjektion vorangestellt werden, aber dennoch nur nach erster Satzsstellung

> Doch! Es war eigentlich gar nicht schlimm.

Nüchtern betracvtet und ohne den ganzen Hokuspokus überzeugt ein weiteres Argument vielleichter. Da die Semantik von "doch" etwas vorhergesagtes vorraussetzt, muss vorher etwas gesagt werden.